# Failed tests in github actions

Tags: reactjs, github-actions

I have a project with react, I created a folder for workflown the actions in github.
But, returned next error.

[image]

My code:

```
name: UnitTests

on: [push]

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '14.x'

      - name: Prepare cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-

      - name: Install node-sass
        run: npm i node-sass

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Run tests
        run: npm run test:ci
```

A package is - `"test:ci": "npm run test --findRelatedTests ./src -b",`

I need solution for this and I can't find it

All tests is correctly

Answer (score 0):

replace `npm ci` with `npm install`